# How to use map in reactjs if a list is present under another list?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

> My reducer class is like this:-

```
    export default function () {
        return [
            {
                testId: 1,
                testName: "80076-Hepatic (Liver) function Panel (PHX)",
                labresultList:[
               {
                labresultId:1,
                loincCodeName:"Protein,Total",
                status: "Under Lab Review",
                value:90.0,
                uom:"g/dl"
                },
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
```

> > Now I am trying to display this data with the help of component like
> >     this:-

```
class LabResultList extends Component{
   renderList() {
        return this.props.labresult.map((test) => {
            return (
                <ul>
                <li key={test.testId} >
                   {test.testName}
                   {test.labresultList.map((result) => {
                        <li key={result.labresultId} >
                        {result.loincCodeName}
                        {result.status}
                        {result.value}{result.uom}
                        </li>

                 })}
                </li>
                </ul>
            );
        });
    }
     render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        );
    }

}
```

> Now I am not able to get the value of labresultList in render , Its
>   showing only the testName as I defined above. How can I use map under
>   the list?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `return` statement inside the inner map function

```js
class LabResultList extends React.Component{
   renderList() {
      var labresult =  [
            {
                testId: 1,
                testName: "80076-Hepatic (Liver) function Panel (PHX)",
                labresultList:[
               {
                labresultId:1,
                loincCodeName:"Protein,Total",
                status: "Under Lab Review",
                value:90.0,
                uom:"g/dl"
                },
                ]
            }

        ]
        return labresult.map((test) => {
            console.log(test.labresultList);
            return (
                <ul>
                <li key={test.testId} >
                   {test.testName}
                   
                   {test.labresultList.map((result) => {
                       return (
                        <li key={result.labresultId} >
                        {result.loincCodeName}
                        {result.status}
                        {result.value}{result.uom}
                        </li>
                         )

                 })}
                </li>
                </ul>
            );
        });
    }
     render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<LabResultList/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably split it into two components. Like this:

```
class LabResult extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <ul>
            {this.props.labresult.map((test) => {
                <LabResultList key={test.testId} labresultList={test.labresultList} />
            })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

class LabResultList extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <li>
                <ul>
                {this.props.labresultList.map((result) => {
                    <li key={result.labresultId}>
                        {result.loincCodeName}
                        {result.status}
                        {result.value}{result.uom}
                    </li>
                })}
                </ul>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```